# BeautifulSoup replace_with for non-standard tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a parser that will take HTML and convert/output to Wiki syntax (`<b>` = `'''`, `<i>` = `''`, etc).

So far, BeautifulSoup seems only capable of replacing the contents within a tag, so `<b>` becomes `<'''>` instead of `'''`. I can use a re.sub() to swap these out, but since BS turns the document into a 'complex tree of Python objects', I can't figure out how to swap out these tags and re-insert them into the overall document.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure there are already tools that would do that for you, but if you are asking about how to do that with `BeautifulSoup`, you can use `replace_with()`, but you would need to preserve the text of the element. Naive and simple example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <b>test1</b>
    <i>test2</i>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for b in soup.find_all("b"):
    b.replace_with("'''%s'''" % b.text)

for i in soup.find_all("i"):
    i.replace_with("''%s''" % i.text)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div>
 '''test1'''
 ''test2''
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. That's what I needed, thank you. There are tools that perform this function to varying degrees, but every one I can find preserves too much of the starting HTML. I want pure conversion to Wiki markup where possible.

Comment: Is there a way to literally change the value `test1` to `test 1212`, with the same replace_with?

Comment: This does not handle nested tags. e.g. data = "<div><b>bold with some <i>italics</i></b></div>" would result in '''bold with some italics'''` rather than `'''bold with some ''italics'''''`. My answer below does

Answer (score 0):

To also handle nested tags, e.g. `"<div><b>bold with some <i>italics</i></b></div>"` you have to be a bit more careful.

I put together the following implementation when I needed to do something similar:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def wikify_tag(tag, replacement):
    tag.insert(0, replacement)
    tag.append(replacement)
    tag.unwrap()

data = """
<div>
    <b>test1</b>
    <i>test2</i>
    <b>bold with some <i>italics</i></b>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for b in soup.find_all("b"):
    wikify_tag(b, "'''")

for i in soup.find_all("i"):
    wikify_tag(i, "''")

print(soup)
```

Prints (note that `.prettify()` makes it look uglier):

```
<div>
'''test1'''
''test2''
'''bold with some ''italics'''''
</div>
```

If you also want to replace tags with wiki-templates you can extend `wikify_tag` to take a start and an end string.